# How to ignore optional prerequisites when installing Oracle database in silent mode?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, silent-installer

I was referring to this [`PAGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e16763/app_nonint.htm#LADBI1341) to install Oracle 11g database in silent mode.

When installing, there were some optional prerequisites which are ignorable:

```
   CAUSE: Some of the optional prerequisites are not met. See logs for details. /oratmp/OraInstall2013-12-22_12-14-09PM/installActions2013-12-22_12-14-09PM.log
   ACTION: Identify the list of failed prerequisite checks from the log: /oratmp/OraInstall2013-12-22_12-14-09PM/installActions2013-12-22_12-14-09PM.log. Then either from the log file or from installation manual find the appropriate configuration to meet the prerequisites and fix it manually.
```

This is different from the GUI based installation method where I can choose to ignore those warnings, however, I didn't see if silent installation provided similar ways to skip those warnings.

Any ideas?

#### update:

Those failed preconditions were some library files missing, e.g.

```
INFO: INFO: Package: compat-libcap1-1.10: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the package "compat-libcap1-1.10" is available on the system.
INFO: INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: INFO: OverallStatus:VERIFICATION_FAILED

INFO: INFO: Package: ksh-...: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the package "ksh-..." is available on the system.
INFO: INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: INFO: OverallStatus:VERIFICATION_FAILED
```

I don't have all the necessary privileges to install those packages, so comes to the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command line arguments are listed in the [OUI guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/em.112/e12255/oui4_product_install.htm#sthref393), and include:

> **-ignoreSysPrereqs** For ignoring the results of the system prerequisite checks.

There is also an `-ignorePrereq` option which doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: -ignorePrereq is the only option that works for me.  -ignoreSysPrereqs fails on my Win7 machine.